# Generating Plots from .csv file

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I'm trying to make several plots of Exoplanet data from NASA's Exoplanet Archive. The problem is nothing I do will return the columns of the csv file with the headers on the first line of the csv file.

The Error I get is

```
    NameError: name 'pl_orbper' is not defined
```

[The DATA I need to use.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPKpF.png)

The code I have currently has not worked though I'm sure I'm close.

```
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import numpy as np

   data = np.genfromtxt("planets.csv",delimiter=',',names=True, unpack=True)

   plt.plot(pl_orbper,pl_bmassj)
   plt.title('Mass vs Period')
   plt.ylabel('Period')
   plt.xlabel('Mass')

   plt.show()
```

If anyone has a better solution with csv.reader or any other ways to read csv files I'd be open to it.

Comment: *"...has not worked..."*  Please explain what did not work.  Did you get an error?  If so, include the complete error message.  Did the code run, but not give you what you expected?  If so, explain what you got and what you expected.

Comment: Let me guess, you are getiing `NameError: name pl_orbper is not defined yet`

Comment: Yes! I can't get the columns to be named after the header. I want to be able to graph with the header names.

Comment: @RexYeigh Well, you need to assign some value to these variables/names, or else how do you expect to be able to use them?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What does 'assign some value' mean?

Comment: You should probably read a Python tutorial. You won't get far if you don't know what assigning to a variable means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
plt.plot(pl_orbper,pl_bmassj)
```

to

```
plt.plot(data['pl_orbper'],data['pl_bmassj'])
```

With the following data:

```
rowid,pl_orbper,pl_bmassj
1, 326.03, 0.320
2, 327.03, 0.420
3, 328.03, 0.520
4, 329.03, 0.620
5, 330.03, 0.720
6, 331.03, 0.820
```

this is the result

[image: Mass vs Period Plot]